# plugin.google.maps not working on iOS but working on Android

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, cordova

Say I have this controller (this is a Cordova/AngularJS application):

```
var Application_MapLocations = index.controller('Application.MapLocations', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$state', function($s, $rs, $state){

    function gmap() {
        var ctx = this;
        var map = plugin.google.maps.Map.getMap();
        map.removeEventListener();
        if (map.markers) {
            angular.forEach(map.markers, function(marker) {
                marker.remove();
            });
        }
        map.markers = [];
        var bounds = new plugin.google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        var boundsLength = 0;
        map.addEventListener(plugin.google.maps.event.MAP_READY, function(map){
            angular.forEach(ctx.points, function(value) {
                map.addMarker({
                    position: new plugin.google.maps.LatLng(value.lat, value.lng),
                    title: value.title,
                    snippet: value.snippet,
                    icon: 'www/img/map_point.png'
                }, function(marker){
                    marker.addEventListener(plugin.google.maps.event.MARKER_CLICK, function() {
                        angular.forEach(map.markers, function(marker) {
                            marker.hideInfoWindow();
                        });
                        marker.showInfoWindow();
                    });
                    map.markers.push(marker);
                    marker.getPosition(function(pos){
                        bounds.extend(pos);
                        if (map.markers.length == ++boundsLength) {
                            map.setCenter(bounds.getCenter());
                            map.setZoom(17);
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        });
        map.showDialog();
    }
    $s.buttons = [
        {id:'btn-section', text:'Seleccione ubicación', section: true, click: function(){ }},
        {id:'carrion', text:'Carrión', section: false, click: gmap, points: [
            {lat: -0.20208, lng: -78.497047, title:"Carrión", snippet:'Direcci&oacute;n: Carri&oacute;n 1030 y Av. 10 de Agosto\nTel&eacute;fonos: 098-742-2271, 02-256-2526, 02-254-3143, 02-290-2434\nFax: 02-256-2385\nContacto: Javier Morquecho dmorquecho@casabaca.com 098-7422271, Dickran Coronel dcoronel@casabaca.com 099-822-2475'}
        ]},
        {id:'cumbaya', text:'Cumbayá', section: false, click: gmap, points: [
            {lat: -0.196783, lng: -78.440718, title:"Cumbayá", snippet:'Direcci&oacute;n: V&iacute;a Interoce&aacute;nica Km 141/2\nTel&eacute;fonos: 098-742-2271, 02-204-0078, 02-289-0038\nContacto: Jofrey Lopez jlopez@casabaca.com 098-640-1447'}
        ]},
        /* *** more place > coortinates here *** */
    ];
    /* *** more code here *** */
}]);
```

Which belongs to a view having the task to show the maps for each location I choose.

In `$scope.buttons` (actually the service is aliased as `$s`) I hold a list of places (they are literal objects with data detailing the coordinates and additional data for rendering). Each place has coordinates. Its mechanics are like this:

1. you see the menu.
2. you click on an item.
3. you see a dialog with the map for the selected locations. you will see the locations as markers.

I'm using the [Phonegap Google Maps Plugin](https://github.com/wf9a5m75/phonegap-googlemaps-plugin) which is causing me many troubles.

The core is in the `gmap` function, which is placed as click handler of each menu element. It proceeds like this:

1. Create a map (or gets it - it is a singleton).
2. Cleans it (removes previous event listeners and markers).
3. When the map is ready, it will (for each coordinate in the selected place):

   - create a marker using the by-param coordinates, by-param title, by-param snippet, and a fixed, custom, image.
   - assigns, to the marker, a click event handler. such handler ensures that only one popup dialog appears on click (previous ones are closed).
   - the created markers is added to the markers list (it is not an actual, existent, property but one I created for the purpose).
   - the marker position is obtained, and a bounds set is extended on such location. the idea behind is to get a "square" able to see all the specified coordinates. if the current marker is the last, the map must center on the center of the bounds so each marker is seen.
4. the dialog is shown.

In Android, this is working like a charm. In iOS is not working at all: the dialog is displayed but no marker is set, no custom image is seen, and no centering on any bounds set is done.

**Q**: What could be screwing it? I'm somehow new to this plugin.

Comment: Thank you for using my plugin. I just want to confirm the map is blank or not?
And you can check JS error using http://phonegap-tips.com/articles/debugging-ios-phonegap-apps-with-safaris-web-inspector.html

Comment: The map is not blank. Is working, but markers aren't loaded (and the application is never focused)

Comment: Have another issue: installing the plugin requires variables, and adding a cordova platform later breaks because the plugin cannot be added to that new platform since the variable is not specified. How can I work-around that? IT does not seem to be a specific issue with your plugin but a by-design bug of cordova.

Comment: I see... Umm, I need more some information to detect what wrong is.

Comment: Well, about the present bug there's no more information as that I gave you. perhaps there's some markup I can add.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60925/discussion-between-wf9a5m75-and-luis-masuelli).

Answer (score 0):

Could you try the following commands?

```
$> cordova plugin rm plugin.google.maps
$> cordova platform rm ios
$> cordova platform add ios android
$> cordova plugin add plugin.google.maps --variable API_KEY_FOR_ANDROID= --variable API_KEY_FOR_IOS=
$> ./platforms/ios/cordova/clean
```